# The program does not work on some devices

Tags: android, kotlin

Good afternoon!
Such a situation, I wrote a program for Android and the following situation arises:
Emulating on Nexus 5 Android 11 (API 30) - works
I run on a real device Honor 9 Android 9 (API 28) - works
Galaxy A50 Android 11 - working

I also run it with friends on their phones and the following happens, which seems strange to me:
realme 6 pro android 11 - not working
Redmi Note 10 pro Android 11 - not working
redmi note 10s android 11 - not working

And most importantly, I can’t track the errors somehow, since the application starts and immediately crashes and the data does not go to Sentry or Firebase

Since I have no applied experience in Kotlin and Java, I ask you for help, what could be the problem and how can I trace the error? For example, is it possible to connect a computer to Redmi note 10 s and see with a logger what happens when the program starts?

```
compileSdkVersion 30
minSdkVersion 24
targetSdkVersion 30
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running this app on various devices using the Android Emulator?

Comment: @Bink yes, try on next devices:
Nexus 5X API 30
Pixel 2 XL API 31
Pixel 3 XL API 30

Comment: @Bink In addition, I tried to use a phone that does not run on, for debugging Some logs AppCompatManager: setIncompatibleAppList exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: miui.security.appcompatibility.AppCompatibilityManager Get miui intent sender : null MiuiUtils: Cannot find package: com.android.quicksearchbox Like something with miui

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to working with Android! device-specific issues have become much less common than they used to be, but they're still around.

For seeing logs from the device, the easiest way is to install Android studio, and enable developer mode on the device. After that, you should be able to connect the device to android studio, and see the logs in the "logcat" window.

To enable developer mode - https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options
To view logs - https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat

Comment: In addition, I tried to use a phone that does not run on, for debugging
Some logs
AppCompatManager: setIncompatibleAppList exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: miui.security.appcompatibility.AppCompatibilityManager

Get miui intent sender : null

MiuiUtils: Cannot find package: com.android.quicksearchbox

Like something with miui